# Paginação com checkboxes no grid carregado com Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net

Na minha página existe um grid com paginação. Ele tem campos para serem checados que não podem ser perdidos quando houver a paginação, porém meu grid está sendo carregado por Linq.

Tentei fazer desta maneira mas não deu certo:

```
protected void grdControleUnimed_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
          {
            foreach (GridViewRow row in grdControleUnimed.Rows)
            {
                var chkSelect = row.FindControl("chkSelect") as CheckBox;
                IDataItemContainer container = (IDataItemContainer)chkSelect.NamingContainer;

                if (chkSelect.Checked)
                {
                    PersistRowIndex(container.DataItemIndex);
                }
                else
                {
                    RemoveRowIndex(container.DataItemIndex);

                }

            }

            ControleUnimedBLL bll = new ControleUnimedBLL();

            grdControleUnimed.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            List<CAD_TBL_CONTROLEUNIMED> list = new List<CAD_TBL_CONTROLEUNIMED>();
            list = bll.GetWhere(Util.String2Short(txtEmpresa.Text), Util.String2Int32(txtMatricula.Text), txtSubMatricula.Text, txtNome.Text, txtCodIdentificacao.Text, ddlNomeUnimed.SelectedValue, ddlMovimentacao.SelectedValue, Util.String2Date(txtDatMovimentacaoIni.Text), Util.String2Date(txtDatMovimentacaoFim.Text), Util.String2Date(txtDatSaidaIni.Text), Util.String2Date(txtDatSaidaFim.Text)).ToList();

            {
                DataTable dt = list.ToDataTable();

                //grdControleUnimed.DataSource = dt;
                grdControleUnimed.DataBind();
                RePopulateCheckBoxes();




            }
        }

        private void PersistRowIndex(int index)
        {

            if (!SelectedUnimedIndex.Exists(i => i == index))
            {

                SelectedUnimedIndex.Add(index);

            }

        }

        private void RemoveRowIndex(int index)
        {
            SelectedUnimedIndex.Remove(index);
        }

        private List<Int32> SelectedUnimedIndex
        {

            get
            {

                if (Session["SELECTED_UNIMED_INDEX"] == null)
                {

                    Session["SELECTED_UNIMED_INDEX"] = new List<Int32>();

                }



                return (List<Int32>)Session["SELECTED_UNIMED_INDEX"];

            }

        }

        private void RePopulateCheckBoxes()
        {

            foreach (GridViewRow row in grdControleUnimed.Rows)
            {

                var chkSelect = row.FindControl("chkSelect") as CheckBox;
                IDataItemContainer container = (IDataItemContainer)chkSelect.NamingContainer;

                if (SelectedUnimedIndex != null)
                {

                    if (SelectedUnimedIndex.Exists(i => i == container.DataItemIndex))
                    {

                        chkSelect.Checked = true;

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```